# Error: invalid input syntax for type integer

Tags: javascript, postgresql, express

I am using postgresql database. I am getting this error "invalid input syntax for type integer" while inserting data into table via express api but the same query is successfully run in pgAdmin.

```
const file = require('../../Pool');
const pool = file.pool;

const createClass= (req,res)=>{

    pool.query("insert into classes(class_name,school_id) values ( 'ICS' , (select id from schools where admin_id = 1))",[className,adminId],
        (err,result)=>{
            if(err){
                console.log('err');
                throw err
            }
            res.status(200).send({"isCreated":true})
        }
    )
}

module.exports = {
    createClass     
}
```

Comment: Please show the entire error message, including the part that shows the value that threw the error. In the meantime I'm going to guess that you have passed in an empty string e.g. ```select ''::integer;
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: ""
LINE 1: select ''::integer; ```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The issue was with my routing pattern.